# Toggle between types depending on an enum case

Tags: swift, generics, enums, uiview

I have a set of color styles that I would like apply to the content of a text view depending on whether it has a style of ColorStyle.dark or ColorStyle.light.

So far I am changing the color by setting the textView to call either BlackTextView() or WhiteTextView() from the view. How can I set the title and the color style dynamically based on the ColorStyle enum?

So for example....

I have an enum to set a colour style, which can be dark, light or none

```
public enum ColorStyle {
    case dark
    case light
    case none
}
```

And from a tableViewCell I can pass a title and the ColorStyle to a custom view

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myView: MyView!
    
    func setup(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
        myView.titleLabel.text = viewModel.titleText
        myView.colorSytle = ColorSytle.dark
    }
}
```

That view (conforms to TextLayout) and can set the textView to have either BlackTextView or WhiteTextView styles

```
public protocol TextLayout {
    associatedtype TextView: UITextView
    var textView: TextView { get }
}

@IBDesignable
public class MyView: View, TextLayout {
    
    public var colorStyle: ColorStyle = .none
    public var textView = BlackTextView()
    // public var textView = WhiteTextView()
}
```

So to summarise, how can I toggle between either the black or white text view color schemes based on a given enum case, but also set the text at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
public class MyView: UIView {
    public var colorStyle: ColorStyle = .none {
      didSet {
        if colorStyle == .light {
          let newView = WhiteTextView()
          newView.text = textView.text
          textView.removeFromSuperview()
          addSubview(newView)
        } else {
          // do same thing for the dark view...
        }
      }
    }
    public var text: String {
      get {
        textView.text
      }
      set {
        textView.text = value
      }
    }
    private var textView: UIView = BlackTextView()
}
```